# How to add googlemap.framework to cocoa touch framework?

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, cocoa-touch

I have multi target application that they have to use google map i decided to create cocoa touch framework and add all google map dependencies and create a view to show google map. i create my framework successfully(i add sample view in that framework and reuse it with success) but when i use that view which extended GMSMapView i get an error about to add google map dependencies to my target. Is there any why to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Any solution for this

Comment: You can add these frameworks like you add them to normal project but where u use your custom framework you should add Google map frameworks in Linked Frameworks and Libraries